# Pass prop through div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to make a div board with reactjs. In order to locate the elements on the board I want to pass props like row and column id.

```
componentDidMount() {
  let board = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < 50; j++){
      board.push(<div className={"board-element"} row={i} col={j}></div>);
    }
  }
  this.setState({elements: board});
}
```

The for loop creates a list of elements and when finished it change the state and set the list to the main div.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="board center-div">
      {this.state.elements} // HERE
    </div>
  );
}
```

But if I inspect the rendered html the row and col are missing.

`<div class="board-element"></div>`

And on the console there is a warning:

```
Warning: Unknown props `row`, `col` on <div> tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change row and col to `data-row` and `data-col`.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Why not to render directly, without storing elements in state?

```
function Board() {
    let board = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < 50; j++){
            board.push(<div key={`${i}-${j}`} className={"board-element"}>{i}{j}</div>);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="board center-div">
            {board}
        </div>
    )
}   



ReactDOM.render(
  <Board name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/81076/)

Comment: The {i}{j} will be appear inside the div and I just need to color the blocks later. Thanks!